# How can I add a confirm box to my Sharepoint page where confirm has additional Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xslt, sharepoint

What I have tried so far is

```
    <input type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick= "initValidation(); if (confirm('Are you sure?')){if(!validateRequiredNew()) return false; javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={ApplicationManagement.aspx}')}} else{}" />
```

I get the following error:

SharePoint Designer cannot render the XSLT in this Data View. Try to undo your changes or re-insert the Data View.Failed setting processor stylesheet : 0x80004005 : Expression expected. initValidation(); if (confirm('Are you sure?')){if(-->!<--validateRequiredNew()) return false; javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={ApplicationManagement.aspx}')}} else{}

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a custom callback function. This would be a function that is called like so.

```
userConfirm('Are you sure', function(answer){

    //answer can be yes or no
    // if (yes) { code }
    // if (no) { code }

});
```

the userConfirm function will be in charge of rendering a custom modal that builds a custom overlaying dialog. You can use jQuery UI's [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) system, or create a dialog yourself. It will then create two buttons that call your passed in callback, and send the correlating event data. Such as clicked "yes" button, or "no" button as the answer variable.

Comment: Hey, I tried that but unfortunately still get an error. I currently have  <input type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick=
    "initValidation(); userConfirm('Are you sure', function(answer){
    if (yes){if(!validateRequiredNew()) return false; javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={ApplicationManagement.aspx}')}}
    if (no) {}});"/>

Comment: is there any malformation of your html? Try removing the JS from the inline onclick and into a script tag. (or external .js file)

Comment: Hey, So I gave it a ago and got this error on Chrome checking it out: Uncaught ReferenceError: userConfirm is not definedonclick @ ApplicationEdit.aspx:1180 it doesn't seem to like the onClick function

Comment: did you include the file? Im curious if its loading the JS file correctly. Open up the console (f12) and see if after the page loads you have access to userConfirm globally. (Dont leave it in the global namespace, ideally tie the event `(element).onclick = function ...` in js)